# sudo apt-get update stuck at connecting to screenshot.getdeb

Tags: 14.04

I run the sudo apt-get update and it got stuck at this point.
prior to this i ran the following commands for installing pycharm.

```
echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-getdeb apps" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb-apps.list

wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -


G580:~$ sudo apt-get update

Ign:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Get:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [1,189 B]          
Get:13 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]        
0% [Connecting to screenshots.getdeb.net (2400:cb00:2048:1::681c:187d)] [Connec^Z
[1]+  Stopped
```

Comment: Two things 1) Is you internet okay, 2) is that repo still there?

Comment: Where did you get that repo link?